# Tomcat jpda port 8000 went to down when connected remotely

Tags: tomcat, jpda

I want to setup remote debug in tomcat with version 9.0.62.

Tomcat run in docker in aws ec2 machine with below commands.

```
export JPDA_ADDRESS=*:8000
export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh jpda run
```

Docker port mapping(i.e. 9114->8000) and aws inbound rules(outbound roles is any) have been configured.

I can observe tomcat is listening at 8000 in the docker container.

Then we I connect to 9114 from Idea IntelliJ remotely, I observe Idea keep in Connecting state for about 30 seconds then end with no message.

I checked immediately and found port 8000 is down.

Question:

- Anyone has direct information about this sort of issue?
- Where can I find out what cause 8000 down? Any log? I checked log files in folder tomcat/logs/ but didn't identify any interest.